# How to clear Dead Region Servers in HBase UI?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have removed a regionserver from my HBase cluster.I removed its hostname from  `$HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers`, and restarted the HBase cluster, but the HBase UI still shows the removed region server as a 'dead' region server.

The 'status' command in the hbase shell also shows it as a dead region server. How should I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 10):

***Cluster getting haunted by dead regionserver*** **:D**

HBase may sometimes still show a *decommissioned* regionserver  as dead. This is because, the WAL (Write-Ahead Log) of the dead regionserver was still in HDFS in the “splitting” state, so from HBase perspective it’s not dead !

So the solution is to go to **WALs** directory in HDFS (usually at /hbase/WALs) and remove the files of the old regionserver.

Found this at this wonderful blog [kill zombie dead regionservers](http://lecluster.delaurent.com/kill-zombie-dead-regionservers/) after much digging.

Comment: In my case, I just deleted all the WALs folders with splitting.